# Selecting multiple DataGrid rows causing error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

First, I'll mention it only fails when `EnableRowVirtualization="True"`
So I know where it's failing, I just don't know how to fix it.

I select multiple rows by selecting the first row, holding the mouse down, and it scrolls down, selecting all rows. As SOON as it gets out of the window, and a new row shows in the window (when it starts scrolling) it fails.

This is the code that is failing. The statement with the error is the one that begins `Dim sn =`

```
'for each asset in the datagrid selected items, add to the selected list
For Each item In asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedItems
    Dim snIndex = asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.Header = "serial num"))
    Dim sn = TryCast(asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedCells(snIndex).Column.GetCellContent(item), TextBlock).Text 'Error here
    variables.selectedAssets.Add(sn)
Next
```

I'm assuming the indexes change as it scrolls, because it only loads what is currently in the window. any way around this?

Error:
    Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: and the error message is????

Comment: Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the DataGrid fixed the issue...

```
EnableRowVirtualization="True"
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
```